# 2 Rewrite Rules for 2 Conditions?

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . Core.php
```

Now I have this above but, would like to know how/if I can mix these into one.
I'm new to this .htaccess so if you could give me a link or somewhere to learn that would be great. ;)

I also couldn't find an awnser that worked on google searches or anything explain how it works so I can configure it to work for me. :L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
#Rewrite /file to /file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite any other request to /core.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /core.php [NC,L]
```

Explaination :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

The line above checks to ensure that the URI.php is a file, if it is an existent php file, then

```
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

The rule rewrites the request to its orignal location request.php (file => file.php)